# PostgreSQL Output to JSON format

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, group-by

I have data that need to result in JSON format. I am using the following code:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'docker' AS type, '564df5a6sdf4654f6da4sf56a' AS id, 1 AS segment, 1 AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'docker' AS type, '564df5a6sdf4654f6da4sf56a' AS id, 2 AS segment, 100 AS value
    )
SELECT type
     , id
     , json_agg(json_build_object(segment, value)) AS json_result
FROM cte
GROUP BY type
       , id
```

Result for json_result column is: `[{"1" : 1}, {"2" : 100}]`

But the desired result is: `{"1" : 1, "2" : 100}`

How to adjust the query so it returns the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`json_object_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.12.1.1.1):

```
SELECT type
     , id
     , json_object_agg(segment, value) AS json_result
FROM cte
GROUP BY type
       , id
```

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed this function.